# Android Button - CustomView

Tags: android, button, material-design, android-custom-view, rippledrawable

I'm working on custom button view. But I've some problems when I try to add a stroke to GradientDrawable.

This is the java code:

```
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    float[] radii = null;
    if (mButtonCornerRadius > 0) {
        radii = new float[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            radii[i] = mButtonCornerRadius;
        }
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {

        int[][] states = new int[][]{
                new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled},// disabled
                new int[]{}
        };

        int[] colors = new int[]{
                mButtonDisabledColor,
                mButtonColor,
                mButtonColor
        };
        ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
        mButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ripple_background);

        RippleDrawable ripple = (RippleDrawable) mButton.getBackground();
        GradientDrawable item = (GradientDrawable) ripple.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.content);
        item.setCornerRadii(radii);
        item.setStroke((int) (mButtonStrokeWidth * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density), mButtonStrokeColor);
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(item.mutate(), colorStateList);
        mButton.setBackgroundTintList(colorStateList);
        mButton.setStateListAnimator(null);
    } else {

        GradientDrawable defaultItem = new GradientDrawable();
        defaultItem.setDither(true);
        defaultItem.setCornerRadius(mButtonCornerRadius * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        defaultItem.setStroke((int) (mButtonStrokeWidth * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density), mButtonStrokeColor);
        defaultItem.setColor(mButtonColor);

        GradientDrawable pressedItem = new GradientDrawable();
        pressedItem.setDither(true);
        pressedItem.setCornerRadius(mButtonCornerRadius * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        pressedItem.setStroke((int) (mButtonStrokeWidth * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density), mButtonStrokeColor);
        pressedItem.setColor(mButtonHoverColor);

        GradientDrawable disabledItem = new GradientDrawable();
        disabledItem.setDither(true);
        disabledItem.setCornerRadius(mButtonCornerRadius * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        disabledItem.setStroke((int) (mButtonStrokeWidth * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density), mButtonStrokeColor);
        disabledItem.setColor(mButtonDisabledColor);

        StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
        stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled, android.R.attr.state_pressed}, pressedItem);
        stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, disabledItem);
        stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled}, defaultItem);
        mButton.setBackgroundDrawable(stateListDrawable);
    }
}
```

This is the XML code v21:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@+id/content">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="7dp" />
            <solid android:color="#660044" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

All works correctly (selector, ripple, color, etc...), I'm not able to add a stroke to my button.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Is mButtonStrokeColor set currectly?

Comment: @CeccoCQ make sure (int) (mButtonStrokeWidth * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density) doesn't return 0